# Woocommerce функция удалить 1 единицу товара из корзины?

Tags: woocommerce

подскажите пожалауйста есть корзина WOocommerce. 2 кнопки + и - для удаление или добавление товара. Я сделал что бы при клике на плюс, была ссылка которая добавляет продукт в корзину. Т.е аналог кнопки купить. И через JS количество меняется. Но каким образом сделать что бы работала кнопка -1 товар. Если вкраце, есть ли функция которая по указанному ID удаляет 1 единицу товара из корзины Заранее спасибо светлые люди

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете просто тригерить корзину при изменении (добавление/удаление), пример с jquery

```
jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
});
```